# Как правильно работать с Cookie в Android

Tags: cookie, android, java

Я реализую запрос к серверу, который устанавливает PHPSESID в куки, я делаю это так:

```
        response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, responseHandler);

        List<Cookie> cookiesReq = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (!cookiesReq.isEmpty()) {
            Log.d(TAG + " : test cookie", url);
            String cookieStr = "";
            for (Cookie cookie : cookiesReq) {
                cookieStr += " " + cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + ";";
                Log.d(TAG, cookieStr);
            }
            if (!cookieStr.equals("")) {
                setCookiesPreference(cookieStr);
            }
        }
```

Т.е. мне в ручную нужно обслуживать куки каждый запрос, есть ли способ сделать это как в браузере, они устанавливались сами без моего присмотра?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону [CookieSyncManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieSyncManager.html)